# How the Promise is resolved in given JavaScript code using Array.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Please refer the following **JavaScript** code:

```js
var arr = [30, 40, 10, 50, 20];
var fun = function(n) {
  console.log("Before Promise => n: " + n);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("After Promise => n: " + n);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Promise Resolved => n: " + n);
      resolve(0);
    }, n * 30);
  });
}
arr.reduce((p, v) => p.then(fun(v)), Promise.resolve(0));
```

**1.** Please correct me if I am wrong that `Array.reduce()` will reduce the above as following `Promise` chain:

```
Promise.resolve(0).then(fun(30)).then(fun(40)).then(fun(10)).then(fun(50)).then(fun(20)).
```

**2.** Why the output is not as below:

```
Promise Resolved => n: 30
Promise Resolved => n: 40
Promise Resolved => n: 10
Promise Resolved => n: 50
Promise Resolved => n: 20
```

**3.** And why the output is as above if I change `n*30` with fixed time say `500` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then` accepts a function as a parameter, but you're doing:

```
p.then(fun(v))
```

This invokes `fun` *immediately*, without waiting for `p` to resolve, and passes the returned Promise to `.then`. It's like doing

```
Promise.then(Promise.resolve(6))
         //  ^^^ but .then only accepts a function as a parameter
```

which doesn't make sense.

Change to a callback which, when called, calls `fun` and returns `fun`'s Promise:

```js
var arr = [30, 40, 10, 50, 20];
var fun = function(n) {
    console.log("Before Promise => n: " + n);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("After Promise => n: " + n);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Promise Resolved => n: " + n);
            resolve(0);
        }, n*30);
    });
}
arr.reduce((p, v) => p.then(() => fun(v)), Promise.resolve(0));
//                          ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Array.reduce()` will reduce the above as following Promise chain

Yes.

> Why the output is not as expected?

Because the promise "chain" is broken. For proper chaining, you need to pass callback functions to `then`:

```
Promise.resolve(0).then(() => fun(30)).then(() => fun(40)).then(() => fun(10)).then(() => fun(50)).then(() => fun(20));
//                      ^^^^^               ^^^^^               ^^^^^               ^^^^^               ^^^^^
```

Do the same in your reducer:

```
arr.reduce((p, v) => p.then(() => fun(v)), Promise.resolve(0));
```